# Is it possible to encrypt an SQLite database when using offline data sync in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, encryption, azure-mobile-services

I have a WinRT app that saves an SQLite database using Azure Mobile Services. I followed the tutorial here: [Using offline data in MobileServices](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/)

I got the database working, but I was wondering if it was possible to either encrypt or password protect the database file that is created with this line

```
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
```

I'm trying to add in an extra layer of security to protect sensitive information. Passwords and such aren't stored in the database, but other information that the user enters may need to be protected and synchronized with a service hosted on Azure. Otherwise, someone could potentially navigate to C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\[packageId]\LocalState
and open the database with any SQLite database browser program. I could encrypt the data that is saved in the classes before it is saved to the database, but it would be preferable to encrypt the database file if possible.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it? If you're storing the user's password, why not prompt them for it whenever they need to authenticate? Encrypting the database isn't going to stop anything, because you need the key to decrypt it, and if the attacker has access to the database then he probably has access to the key as well.

Comment: The program is mainly going to be used for data entry and I want to secure the database because it'll be saving potentially sensitive data. If it's not possible to do that then I'll just have to encrypt the data before it is saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Services doesn't currently have an API to password protect or encrypt the SQLite database on the device. You could contribute or provide a feedback to the [open source project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services).

Comment: Is it possible now?